# My app is not showing the name from the manifest file

Tags: android

I'm currently doing some testing on my android app, but without being plugged in by USB cable to my laptop. On my "app list" (the one you get by pressing the 3x3 grid of white dots on the bottom centre of the home screen of your phone), I can see my app - the icon is showing but the app name isn't. I've included my manifest and strings file - can anyone see what is wrong please? It doesn't seem to be taking the label tag from the application section in the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackage.excursions">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/custommarkerblank"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Excursions"
        android:label="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

The strings file (with the API key removed) is this:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Excursions</string>
<string name="title_activity_excursions"></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is beacuse the laucher activity also has no label! Try adding a label

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I feel foolish for asking this, but in my research on this (including posts here on StackOverflow), it is the application section that is mentioned in regard to this problem, and not the area for activity. I wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beacuse the laucher activity also has no label! Try adding a label.

Answer (score 1):

Your Launcher activity has no label, try to add label for the launcher activity.

Answer (score 1):

that label needs a string resource assigned:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

or when there are several launch-able activities:

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_excursions"
```